# Parsing a signed integer into a date

Tags: date, math

Given a signed integer **x**, how could I convert this into a date relative to year 1, day 1 (like to_date in SQL) with the formatting day/month/year. My pseudocode solution for dealing with positive values was easy (but not elegant):

```
while x > 0
if(x > 364)
    if (leap_year(year))
        x -= 366
    else
        year += 1
else
    for (i = 12; i > 0; i++)
        if days_to_month[i] < x
            month = i + 2
            day += x - days_to_month[i]
            x = 0
        else if days_to_month[i] == x
            month = i + 1
            day = 1
            x = 0
        else if days_remaining < 31
            month = 1
            day = 1
            x = 0

return (day, month year)
```

Like I said, it is a very messy solution but I'm not too worried for the time being. I am currently working on a way to represent negative values as BC dates.

This function currently doesn't support negative inputs and that is my end goal. I can't really wrap my head around how to write this and haven't been able to find a solution online that doesn't use an external library (I am trying not to use one).

Comment: I wasn't sure whether to put it in a kind of pseudocode or the language I'm writing in (rust) seeing as its less of a rust question and more of a general math question. Should I edit my question and use my real code? Not sure as I haven't posted a math tag question before

Comment: It's helpful to indicate that it's pseudocode; otherwise it looks like poorly written C or Java.

Comment: Sorry about that, will remember for next time

Comment: Out of curiosity, why don't you want to use an external library? Date handling is extremely complicated, and using third-party libraries is easy as can be in Rust. It's not great to roll your own unless you're just doing it as a learning exercise.

Comment: Yes.  No matter how complicated dealing with external libraries is in whatever language you are using, it is almost certainly going to be easier than properly handling dates.  And if you have to handle datetimes, fageddaboudit

Comment: Nothing against libraries, I'm honestly just interested to see if anybody has an interesting solution to a question like this

Comment: I recommend posting real Rust code. The details are important in programming, and we lose them if you post pseudocode. For example, what is `days_to_month`? We can't tell. What does `while x > 0` apply to? It's hard to be sure due to the lack of curly braces. (But still, upvoted. It's a good question and these aren't fatal flaws.)

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Are there any **specific** cases that currently are not working as expected?